# No latest (4.3.0.) openCV library in opencv-python via PIP

Tags: python, pip, opencv

Im using PyCharm to connect libraries but suppose is similar to using pip install opencv-python
Pycharm shows version 4.2.0.34 for opencv-python library when actual is 4.3.0

going to https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ i see only i see 4.2.0 version only.

Going to https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python I can see it was updated two month ago when 4.3 is out and even I can see some note of 4.3. 
But Python shows version 4.2.0.34 and features of version 4.3.0 are not working.

Am I doing something wrong or is the only way to have 4.3 build it from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** As of 6th July 2020, `opencv-python` wheels for 4.3.0 are available on PyPI. You can see that in the releases link below, and the issue linked to below is now closed. You should be able to install it via `pip` in the normal way.

**Original:**
According to the [releases page for `opencv-python`](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/releases), the latest built version is 4.2.0.34. There is also an [open issue for 4.3 not being available](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/316), where the build maintainer explained that the newest version of OpenCV can't be built with the same automatic system as the previous versions (it can't be built with manylinux1), so it's not just a matter of triggering a new build. In other words, if you want OpenCV 4.3 for Python on your computer, yes, you will need to build it yourself.