# How to update to opencv 4.3.0

Tags: opencv, version

I am trying to import dnn_superres model but can't import due to lesser version of OpenCV so can anybody let me help that how can I update my OpenCV version 4.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall the existing `opencv` installation:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Then use the following command to install the 4.3.0 version:

```
pip install opencv-python==4.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using pip will not give you version 4.3.0, because it is [not released on pip yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089322/no-latest-4-3-0-opencv-library-in-opencv-python-via-pip).

I would suggest OpenCV building from source. For example, you can use [this](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) tutorial for Linux; and [this](https://bleedai.com/installation-of-opencv-4-3-0-in-windows-10-from-source-with-nvidia-gpu-support-non-free-flags-enabled/) one for Windows.

Edit: OpenCV 4.3.0 is now available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/).